# Why does view with layout_marginTop set and gravity=bottom placed inside horizontal LinearLayout cause margin to appear at the bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've tried to add view with `layout_marginTop` set and `gravity=bottom` inside a horizontal `LinearLayout` and it causes margin to appear at the bottom for no reason.

I'm aware that kind of layout could be build differently but I can't understand why I'm getting such result.

Here is the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="TEST"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Any ideas with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through the source code, it seems that the root cause of this behavior is the fact that `LinearLayout` aligns its child `View`s by their baselines by default. When it measures out the vertical offsets for the child `View`s, it takes into account the [sum of the vertical margins](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#1144). These [offsets](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#1159) are then applied [after the "normal" top (y) coordinates are calculated](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#1715) for the child `View`s.

The upshot of all this is, if you want your `TextView` aligned right at the bottom, set the `LinearLayout`'s `baselineAligned` attribute to `false`.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView is set with Its own LAYOUT GRAVITY to bottom, i.e. TextView's whole body is aligned to bottom, it won't make difference if orientation is horizontal, because it is linearLayout it won't work with marginTop when layoutGravity of View is set to Bottom, remove layoutGravity and keep marginTop it will come near to the top with mentioned margin.!

**Why it is not on the base.?**
because you have given it a margin and when you are giving it some value provided you have given it layoutGravity of **Bottom** already so it takes the bottom as it base align and gives margin from it.!

Hope i helped you partially if not completely.

Comment: Well, I know how to achieve the desired result. I just don't know why this is  laid out that way. Where does the bottom margin come from?

Comment: As i sadd in the aswer buddy, U r using layoutGravity so it will ultimately put the view on the bottom,top,centre, as given in the value. You are providing it the bottom so it goes to bottom.... layoutGravity plays the part in positioning the view on the display.

Comment: But mate it's not positioned at the very bottom but near the bottom, look at the screen.

Comment: @Digger i edited my answer , hope it is clear to you.